# Using a generator in Pyramid view called by Ajax

Tags: python, generator, pyramid

I would like to lazily load items to my HTML. Each item is computationally laborious, so I only would like to load and process the bare minimum necessary. I thought a generator would be a good solution to this.

In a nutshell, I have something like

```
@view_config(renderer='json', xhr=True, route_name='load_more_posts')
def load_more_posts(self):  
    items = Render.get_items(5)
    return items
```

Where `Render` is just my class name, and `get_items` is a method which calls my generator's `next()` method `5` times, each time retrieving a new item and adding to a list. Now I have a list `items` and I want to simply output it via JSON.

How can I make this work? Every time I call this view with my AJAX call, the generator is 're-instantiated' and I only ever get the first 5 items. Is there a way to have this generator persist between AJAX calls so subsequent calls to it will progress through it and finally exhaust it?

Thank you.

Comment: This Is Not How Web Works :) Consider multiple users accessing your application at the same time. Consider several instances of your application running at the same time (threading, multiple worker processes on the same machine, multiple machines behind a load-balancer).

Comment: These are all great points. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persisting your generator is not a good idea. It would bring statefulness to your HTTP app.

Instead, use paging.

`/posts?page=2`

Comment: That's it. Almost every REST API provider cares about this topic even StackOverflow (http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging) or Twitter (https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-housekeeping). Let the client have explicit control about these calls. Later on apply common HTTP caching strategies to take the burden from server if possible.

Comment: I did some reading and you're definitely spot on with this. Thanks for the help.